# Как реализовать Fragment.onAttach() в адаптере (RecyclerView.Adapter)

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Разрабатывается приложение, в котором используются фрагменты. Пытаюсь реализовать смену фрагмента по нажатию на любой item в recyclerView. Обработка нажатия происходит в адаптере.

> TimeReportAdapter.java

```
public class TimeReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

public OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener mTimeReportAdapterCallBack;


public interface OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener {
    void onMinuteReportAction();
}

private Context context;
private List<TimeReport> mReportList = Collections.emptyList();
private SharedPreferences mSettings;
private static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "myValues";
private static final String APP_PREFERENCES_DATE = "date";
private Intent mIntent;

public TimeReportAdapter(Context context, List<TimeReport> reportList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mReportList = reportList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_time_report, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final TimeReport report = mReportList.get(position);
    holder.tv_time.setText(report.getmTime());
    holder.tv_count.setText(String.valueOf(report.getmCount()));
    // обработка нажатия по item
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // запись в SharedPreferences
            mSettings = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
            editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_DATE, report.getmTime());
            editor.apply();
            Log.d("savedSharedPreferences", APP_PREFERENCES_DATE +" "+ report.getmTime());

            // вызов смены фрагмента
            mTimeReportAdapterCallBack.onMinuteReportAction();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mTimeReportAdapterCallBack = (OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mReportList.size();
}}
```

> TimeReportFragment.java

```
public class TimeReportFragment extends Fragment {

private static View mRootView = null;
private ImageButton mRefreshBtn = null; // кнопка "обновить"
private ArrayList<TimeReport> mTimeReports = null;
private TimeReportAdapter mTimeReportAdapter = null;
private RecyclerView mRecycler = null;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar = null; // анимация загрузки
private LinearLayout mHeader = null;
private View mLine = null;

public Adapter adapter;

public TimeReportFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_time_report, container, false);
    initializeViews();

    doSendTimeReportRequest(); // отправка запроса, получение, парсинг json, установка в recyclerView

    mRefreshBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            doSendTimeReportRequest();
        }
    });

    return mRootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mTimeReportAdapter.setInterface((TimeReportAdapter.OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener) activity);
        //mTimeReportFragmentCallBack = (TimeReportFragment.OnTimeReportFragmentActionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnTimeReportFragmentActionListener");
    }
}
```

> TimeReportAdapter.java (обновленный)

```
public class TimeReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

public OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener mTimeReportAdapterCallBack;
public interface OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener {
    void onMinuteReportAction();
}

private Fragment fragment;
private MainActivity mainActivity;

private Context context;
private List<TimeReport> mReportList = Collections.emptyList();
private SharedPreferences mSettings;
private static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "myValues";
private static final String APP_PREFERENCES_DATE = "date";

public TimeReportAdapter(Context context, List<TimeReport> reportList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mReportList = reportList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_time_report, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final TimeReport report = mReportList.get(position);
    holder.tv_time.setText(report.getmTime());
    holder.tv_count.setText(String.valueOf(report.getmCount()));
    // обработка нажатия по item
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // запись в SharedPreferences
            mSettings = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
            editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_DATE, report.getmTime());
            editor.apply();
            Log.d("savedSharedPreferences", APP_PREFERENCES_DATE +" "+ report.getmTime());

            // вызов смены фрагмента
            mTimeReportAdapterCallBack.onMinuteReportAction();
            //mTimeReportAdapterCallBack.onMinuteReportAction();
        }
    });
}

public void setInterface(OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener myInterface) {
    this.mTimeReportAdapterCallBack = myInterface;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mReportList.size();
}}
```

Конструкция приложения такова, что смена всех фрагментов происходит в MainActivity с которым взаимодействуют фрагменты через интерфейсы. Приложение разрабатываю не с нуля, поэтому структуру менять не могу.

**Чтобы все заработало необходимо реализовать метод onAttach(). Но для этого нужно наследоваться от Fragment, а не RecyclerView.Adapter. Как быть?**

**Вопрос: как реализовать метод onAttach(), или как по другому реализовать вызов mTimeReportAdapterCallBack.onMinuteReportAction() чтобы он не был null?**

Answer (score 1):

onAttach - это метод фрагмента. Реализовать его в адаптере невозможно.

Вам надо действовать иначе. Судя по приведённому коду, вам лучше всего сделать сеттер для вашего интерфейса и передавать его экземпляр из фрагмента в адаптер при вызове onAttach у фрагмента.

Примерно так:

```
public class Fr extends Fragment {

    Adapter adapter;

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        adapter.setInterface((OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener) activity);
    }

    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        adapter.setInterface(null);
    }
}

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    public void setInterface(Interface myInterface) {
        this.myInterface = myInterface;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделал как Вы посоветовали. Теперь при запуске фрагмента, на котором происходит нажатие по recyclerView приложение вылетает с ошибкой: ...(consolemobileadmin.Adapters.TimeReportAdapter$OnTimeReportAdapterActionListener)' on a null object reference. Не пойму, почему он null. Добавил код в вопросе.

Comment: @zepelinjam, видимо onAttach вызывается до создания адаптера и, в итоге, у адаптера не вызывается. Вызовите в таком случае сеттер сразу после создания адаптера ещё.

Answer (score 1):

В адаптере есть следующий метод, переопределите его и получите context из recyclerview, context и есть ваше activity которое можно преобразовать в интерфейс

```
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        context = recyclerView.getContext();
}
```